# dkim fail: public key doen't seems to be valid

Tags: email, email-signature, dkim

I created a public/private rsa key pair with Puttygen. I added the following record to dns but dkim fails. It seems there is some problems with my public key. I checked it with https://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck and found that it is not valid.

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; h=sha256; p=AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEArv5BxLaIE0HYkr1RSIqhAUUZ3OPiV81e8d0Q7Iv2jIQ9LCxnw831HteCwMFzry352dW2UfbmjVMesNOiyZWrE2oHYCG/hQ6ocl5KIY/cNrymZYkzFgnG/HeQBU+YZWkRyT7tNzG6IhgFBs7BZdO1iyEJNaAjsdXZJuv7H2Z4r5aDk8n1A0bzfYGhiIX4uSyUbV6T5njsfBX7Un0IBvf/nbEj6NJ+idF0puoz0gWffRWu1zoJfFs8ddjHSGsp4bKQjsm6msAvc7LZ6csmNec1G9UdUAzd+rxETaRIew7p3E6PiPbTfGuLr283V+SZMMume6bgyK3Bg7/bKv80vD71mw==
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The key itself must be packaged in a specific format, and you're using the wrong one.

An RSA keypair isn't just a piece of random text – internally it consists of a few large numbers, and different programs have different ways of encoding those numbers into bytes (serializing them). For example, *n* might go before *e* or after it; they might be stored big-endian or little-endian; etc. Some formats have a field indicating the key type itself, some don't.

The text you're trying to use with `p=` is in SSHv2 format. However, DKIM requires it to be in PKCS#1 "RSAPublicKey" format (aka OpenSSL PEM format), although the DKIM specification later contradicts itself by showing an example in X.509 "SubjectPublicKeyInfo" format, and many implementations indeed accept both.

PuTTYgen can output *neither* of those public key formats – you will need to use a different tool. It would be best to use the key generation tools that your DKIM signing software provides.

(If your DKIM software doesn't come with any, then the `openssl` command should do the job – its `genrsa` and `genpkey` commands can create a new keypair, then `rsa` or `pkey` to extract the public half.)

Comment: Thank you. I generated the keys online and now DKIM works.